# com.parse.ParseException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempted to find non-existent uuid

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using parse android SDK in my app. Here is my login activity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    EditText username, password;
    Button login;
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, LogSignActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        initializeViews();
        if (prefs.getBoolean(PreferenceStrings.logged, false)) {
            username.setText(prefs.getString(PreferenceStrings.uname, ""));
            password.setText(prefs.getString(PreferenceStrings.pwd, ""));
            dialog.show();
            ParseUser.logInInBackground(username.getText().toString(), password
                    .getText().toString(), new LogInCallback() {

                @Override
                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    if (e != null) {
                        prefs.edit()
                                .putBoolean(PreferenceStrings.logged, false)
                                .commit();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (user == null) {
                        prefs.edit()
                                .putBoolean(PreferenceStrings.logged, false)
                                .commit();
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "User not found!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (!user.isAuthenticated()) {
                        prefs.edit()
                                .putBoolean(PreferenceStrings.logged, false)
                                .commit();
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                "User is not authenticated!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        prefs.edit().putBoolean(PreferenceStrings.logged, true)
                                .commit();
                        prefs.edit()
                                .putString(PreferenceStrings.uname,
                                        username.getText().toString()).commit();
                        prefs.edit()
                                .putString(PreferenceStrings.pwd,
                                        password.getText().toString()).commit();
                        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                                HomeActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        TextView back = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nav_back);
        back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                        LogSignActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });
        login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (username.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please enter username!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (password.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please enter password!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    dialog.show();
                    ParseUser.logInInBackground(username.getText().toString(),
                            password.getText().toString(), new LogInCallback() {

                                @Override
                                public void done(ParseUser user,
                                        ParseException e) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                    if (e != null) {
                                        prefs.edit()
                                                .putBoolean(
                                                        PreferenceStrings.logged,
                                                        false).commit();
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    if (user == null) {
                                        prefs.edit()
                                                .putBoolean(
                                                        PreferenceStrings.logged,
                                                        false).commit();
                                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                                "User not found!",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    } else if (!user.isAuthenticated()) {
                                        prefs.edit()
                                                .putBoolean(
                                                        PreferenceStrings.logged,
                                                        false).commit();
                                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                                "User is not authenticated!",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    } else {
                                        prefs.edit()
                                                .putBoolean(
                                                        PreferenceStrings.logged,
                                                        true).commit();
                                        prefs.edit()
                                                .putString(
                                                        PreferenceStrings.uname,
                                                        username.getText()
                                                                .toString())
                                                .commit();
                                        prefs.edit()
                                                .putString(
                                                        PreferenceStrings.pwd,
                                                        password.getText()
                                                                .toString())
                                                .commit();
                                        startActivity(new Intent(
                                                LoginActivity.this,
                                                HomeActivity.class));
                                        startActivity(new Intent(
                                                LoginActivity.this,
                                                HomeActivity.class));
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void initializeViews() {
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_log);
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    }
    }
```

I was able to login successfully, but after some logins, I was unable to login and the following error is returned from Parse: 
[image]
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug, and has been verified by the Parse team for the iOS API (my hunch is that it runs deeper and is the same bug you are seeing here on the Android side).

You can find out more here:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/614018488703097/

Until it's resolved, it might be wise to turn off the Local Data Store and see if that helps.