# Parse SDK for iOS throw exception Attempted to find non-existent uuid while call pin

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm using parse for iOS version 1.6 through cocoapods.

When I call the function pin for a PFObject the function throw the exception:

NSInternalInconsistencyException => Attempted to find non-existent uuid 085CC82A-3093-4F48-8576-382C1B0EC02B

the code looks like this:

```
 [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Product"];
 [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        for (Product* obj in objects) {
            [self.allProducts addObject:obj];
            @try {
                [obj pin];
            }
            @catch (NSException *exception) {
                NSLog(@"Log => %@", exception);
            }
        }
    }
 }];
```

The app shows this in the console:

```
2014-12-17 20:38:01.116 Nobly Dev[478:57860] Exception => Attempted to find non-existent uuid 085CC82A-3093-4F48-8576-382C1B0EC02B
```

Previously I enable the local datastore with the call to [Parse enableLocalDatastore] and I cam correctly store other objects in the local datastore.

I'm running the application in an iPad 3 with iOS 8.1

I found this other question [com.parse.ParseException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempted to find non-existent uuid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26751417/com-parse-parseexception-java-lang-illegalstateexception-attempted-to-find-non) but without answers...

Any ideas?

PS: this is part of the report from crashlytics

```
    Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
    Attempted to find non-existent uuid 085CC82A-3093-4F48-8576-382C1B0EC02B

    >>>  PFOfflineStore.m line 944
    __52-[PFOfflineStore _getPointerAsyncWithUUID:database:]_block_invoke

    BFTask.m line 335
    __48-[BFTask continueWithExecutor:withSuccessBlock:]_block_invoke

    BFTask.m line 287
    __41-[BFTask continueWithExecutor:withBlock:]_block_invoke_2

    BFExecutor.m line 43
    __29+[BFExecutor defaultExecutor]_block_invoke_2

    BFExecutor.m line 107
    -[BFExecutor execute:]

    BFTask.m line 284
    __41-[BFTask continueWithExecutor:withBlock:]_block_invoke

    BFTask.m line 319
    -[BFTask continueWithExecutor:withBlock:]

    BFTask.m line 331
    -[BFTask continueWithExecutor:withSuccessBlock:]

    BFTask.m line 341
    -[BFTask continueWithSuccessBlock:]

    PFOfflineStore.m line 939
    -[PFOfflineStore _getPointerAsyncWithUUID:database:]

    PFOfflineStore.m line 282
    __51-[PFOfflineStore fetchObjectLocallyAsync:database:]_block_invoke_2

    PFInternalUtils.m line 725
    +[PFInternalUtils traverseObject:usingBlock:seenObjects:]

    PFInternalUtils.m line 705
    __57+[PFInternalUtils traverseObject:usingBlock:seenObjects:]_block_invoke
    16
    CoreFoundation  
    __NSArrayEnumerate + 386
    17
    CoreFoundation  
    -[NSArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 62

    PFInternalUtils.m line 704
    +[PFInternalUtils traverseObject:usingBlock:seenObjects:]

    PFInternalUtils.m line 719
    +[PFInternalUtils traverseObject:usingBlock:seenObjects:]

    PFInternalUtils.m line 705
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in Parse.com API version 1.6. They have currently reproduced it in-house and are working on a solution. (According to their user forums, they are aware of the problem as of 2014/12/15.) For now, your best bet it wait before using the iOS localDataStore.

For more info, see the bug report here:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/614018488703097/

Comment: I still see this issue in Parse 1.7.4

Comment: Same thing with 1.7.5

Comment: Same thing with 1.8.2

Comment: Same thing with 1.15.4